# Excel and SQL - connection between Excel files

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have the (final) code I got on the internet.
In this line of code gives error in WHERE, since it is a text:

```
strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
" FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Vendedor] = Murilo;"
```

Substituting for this below does not give error in WHERE, being a number:

```
strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
" FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Total] >= 100000;"
```

And I ask: do you need this semicolon at the end?

Here is the complete code, and I also ask:
Need to set Nothing at the end of the code for the variables conn, rst, and fld?
For full code to run, do I need to add some library?

```vb
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim wkCaminho, wkArquivo As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim fld As Object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    wkCaminho = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    wkArquivo = "MATRIZ DE DADOS.xlsx"
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete
    ' Hard code database location and name
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='" & wkCaminho & wkArquivo & "';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

'    strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
'    " FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Total] >= 100000;"

    strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
    " FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Vendedor] = Murilo;"

    ' Open the db connection
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' column headers
    I = 0
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A1").Activate
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, I) = fld.Name
        I = I + 1
    Next fld

    ' data rows
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close

    MsgBox "Successfully ran SQL query!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank's.
And set Nothing and library?

Answer (score 2):

```
...WHERE [VENDAS$].[Vendedor] = Murilo;"
```

should be

```
...WHERE [VENDAS$].[Vendedor] = 'Murilo'"
```

Non-numeric fields need quotes around values.

I typically omit the semicolon - I have found instances where it's a problem if you include it but I've never run into issues when leaving it out.